# Why do the source folders in package explorer appear in not alphabetical order

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm looking at a few projects in Eclipse's Package Explorer.

I expect to see the items listed in this order:

```
My Awesome Project 
+ src/main/java
+ src/test/java
+ src/test/resources
```

The first project in my list meets this expectation, but the second project appears in this order

```
My Less Awesome Project 
+ src/test/java
+ src/test/resources
+ src/main/java
```

Is there a setting I can change to get the source folders to appear in the way I expect them to?  I'm using Luna-Eclipse

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's just how your build path is configured. Right-click on the project, select Build Path / Configure Build Path, then under "Order and Export" you can move the source folders etc up and down.

Comment: Right! The order is also important for class loading. For example, using jmockit library you have to put the jmockit.jar on the top of the classpath.

Comment: You were right, but now I'm puzzled why this is a feature. What is the value in rendering Build Path order in the Package Explorer?  Is there some subtle use besides seeing the files in my Package Explorer that I'm missing?

Comment: @MedicineMan: Well I guess it makes the build path order very clear. Can't say I've used the feature myself particularly.